# MS Access SQL using multiple left joins

Tags: ms-access

The below join works in Access, but I need to add a fourth join.

```
FROM ((Agents
LEFT JOIN Resignation_Pool    ON Agents.PF = Resignation_Pool.PF)
LEFT JOIN Teams               ON Agents.Team = Teams.ID)
LEFT JOIN Skills              ON Agents.PF = Skills.PF
```

When I add the fourth join, it doesn't work.  I know Access is weird about the parenthesis, but I think I have them where they belong.  The query just runs forever doing nothing (it shouldn't run long at all) and I end up cancelling it.  Any suggestions?

```
FROM (((Agents
LEFT JOIN Resignation_Pool    ON Agents.PF = Resignation_Pool.PF)
LEFT JOIN Teams               ON Agents.Team = Teams.ID)
LEFT JOIN Skills              ON Agents.PF = Skills.PF)
LEFT JOIN OneMore             ON Agents.OM = OneMore.OM
```

Here is the code that works - my actual query instead of one I found that looked similar.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A02.PID, A02.PS, A02.PN, A02.PM, C01.RC, C01.IC, C01.RD 
INTO AutoCR 
FROM ((02_CorrectResults A02 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_pol_PGI C01 
  ON (A02.PID = C01.PID and C01.PS = '999' and C01.PEDate >= #04/01/2012#)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_pol_IL C02 
  ON C01.PID = C02.PID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_pol_UN C03 
  ON C02.ILID = C03.ILID
```

I add another join and this doesn't work. I tried using inner join instead but Access doesn't like that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A02.PID
, A02.PS
, A02.PN
, A02.PM
, C01.RC
, C01.IC
, C01.RD
, C04.CCode
, C04.PCode
, C04.CForm,
INTO AutoCR 
FROM (((02_CorrectResults A02 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_rol_PGI C01 
  ON (A02.PID = C01.PID and C01.PS = '999' and C01.PEDate >= #04/01/2012#)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_rol_IL C02 
  ON C01.PID = C02.PID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_rol_UN C03 
  ON C02.ILID = C03.ILID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_rol_HO C04 
  ON C03.UnID = C04.UnID
```

Comment: What happen when you remove the parenthesis's?
Can you show the entire query?

Comment: Designer give the error Microsoft Access can't represent the join expression in Design view.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: As one person said, try setting up what you need in the designer and see what it looks like.  Also, when doing complex sub query joins like this access works much better if you create a query object for the subquery and then tie to that.

Answer (score 6):

You have a trailing `,` in your query. Remove it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A02.PID
, A02.PS
, A02.PN
, A02.PM
, C01.RC
, C01.IC
, C01.RD
, C04.CCode
, C04.PCode
, C04.CForm,   <--- this was the problem
INTO AutoCR 
FROM (((02_CorrectResults A02 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_rol_PGI C01 
  ON (A02.PID = C01.PID and C01.PS = '999' and C01.PEDate >= #04/01/2012#)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_rol_IL C02 
  ON C01.PID = C02.PID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_rol_UN C03 
  ON C02.ILID = C03.ILID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_rol_HO C04 
  ON C03.UnID = C04.UnID
```