# JOIN each row only once — arrange (distribute) rows 1 to 1

Tags: mysql, sql, join, row-number

I have two tables to join, and I want each row to be joined only once. Here is sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id smallint, val varchar(1) );
CREATE TABLE B (id smallint, val varchar(1) );
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'd');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2, 'x'), (3, 'y'), (4, 'z'), (3, 'k');
```

When we join on id we obtain:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id;
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | val  | id   | val  |
+------+------+------+------+
|    2 | b    |    2 | x    |
|    3 | c    |    3 | y    |
|    3 | d    |    3 | y    |
|    3 | c    |    3 | k    |
|    3 | d    |    3 | k    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

What I want is either:

```
+------+------+------+------+            +------+------+------+------+
| id   | val  | id   | val  |            | id   | val  | id   | val  |
+------+------+------+------+     or     +------+------+------+------+
|    2 | b    |    2 | x    |            |    2 | b    |    2 | x    |
|    3 | c    |    3 | y    |            |    3 | d    |    3 | y    |
|    3 | d    |    3 | k    |            |    3 | c    |    3 | k    |
+------+------+------+------+            +------+------+------+------+
```

The order and arrangement don’t matter.

Is it possible? How?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549626/3628160) I need to specify how to select the matching row. In that case I guess would need to check in a subquery if the row of the joined table has already been used; or a kind of counter related to the id... but I do not know how to write this.

**Edit:**

To clarify I want each row with id 3 to be mapped with another one in the joined table, such as each row is mapped only once (I am also interested to know what happens when the number of rows with same id is different in the two tables):

```
(3, c) -> (3, y) [join only with the first row such as B.id = 3]
(3, d) -> (3, k) [the first row has been used, so map with (and only with) the second row such as B.id = 3]
```

But as I said mapping may be in any other order (e.g. mapping rows in reverse order).

Comment: You can achieve the result using a partial `GROUP BY` but what is the point? The result will be non-deterministic.

Comment: That **`or`** in your wanting part of question is very confuser, I can't make a specific answer.

Comment: @SalmanA Do you have an example of query? I did not know a SELECT could produce non-deterministic results. But anyway if it gives me what I want it is fine.
@ shA.t Well, if you can produce either of the results with the sample data I am happy.

Comment: A partial GROUP BY would look like `SELECT a.id, a.val, b.val FROM a JOIN b ... GROUP BY a.id, a.val`. The non-deterministic part is that there is no guarantee which b.val is returned for each (a.id, a.val) pair.

Comment: Ok, this is the same method as in the first answer of Galma88. 
Rather than non-deterministic you mean implementation defined? The later depends on the specifications of the GROUP BY clause but the former depends on its implementation. My tests consistently (looks deterministic :o ) give me the wrong output with this query (it is always grouped on the first row such that A.id = 3 — i.e (3,c)).

Comment: The phrase "doesn't matter" is often symptomatic of poor design. It *should* matter!

Comment: *I am also interested to know what happens when the number of rows with same id is different in the two tables* - so what should happen, and why then in your example is the number of rows with the same Id the same?

Comment: @Strawberry I think that depends on the problem. For what I want to do as long as the values are valid and compatible (same `id`) any combinaison is fine. In my case `id` is a md5 hash + filesize, and `val` a filepath.

Comment: @Strawberry You are right a better example would have enabled me requiring exactly what I wanted, but I did not want to set the bar to high. Defining the behaviour in this case was a secondary objective.  After posting this line I figured out that this behaviour would be defined by the type of JOIN used, so I did not add more in my own answer either. An INNER JOIN fits my needs.

Comment: I think the bar can be moved up a couple of rungs without causing too much consternation around here. ;-)

Comment: Your description of what you want is still unintelligible.

Comment: Is the title unclear? I gave a specific example of what I want given a specific input. Please point out what is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it thanks to this [blog post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/27/simulating-the-sql-row_number-function/):

```
SELECT A2.id, A2.val, B2.val FROM (
    SELECT l.id, l.val, COUNT(*) AS n1 FROM A AS l JOIN A AS r ON l.id = r.id AND l.val >= r.val GROUP BY l.id, l.val
) AS A2 JOIN (
    SELECT l.id, l.val, COUNT(*) AS n2 FROM B AS l JOIN B AS r ON l.id = r.id AND l.val >= r.val GROUP BY l.id, l.val
) AS B2 ON
A2.id = B2.id AND n1 = n2;
```

The result is:

```
+------+------+------+
| id   | val  | val  |
+------+------+------+
|    2 | b    | x    |
|    3 | c    | k    |
|    3 | d    | y    |
+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/166bc/12)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id smallint, val varchar(1) );
CREATE TABLE B (id smallint, val varchar(1) );
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'd');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2, 'x'), (3, 'y'), (4, 'z'), (3, 'k');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
        aa.id  as aid
      , aa.val as aval
      , bb.id  as bid
      , bb.val as bval
from (
      select
            @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=a.id,@row_num+1,1)AS RowInGroup
          , a.id
          , a.val
          , @prev_value := a.id
      from (
            SELECT id, val 
            FROM A
            group by id, val
            /* order by ?? */
              ) a
            CROSS JOIN (
                        SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :=''
                       ) vars
      ) aa
INNER JOIN (
          select
                @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=b.id,@row_num+1,1)AS RowInGroup
              , b.id
              , b.val
              , @prev_value := b.id
          from (
                SELECT id, val 
                FROM B
                group by id, val
                /* order by ?? */
                  ) b
                CROSS JOIN (
                            SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :=''
                           ) vars
          ) bb on aa.id = bb.id and aa.RowInGroup = bb.RowInGroup
order by
        aa.id
      , aa.val
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/166bc/12/0)**:

```
| id | val | id | val |
|----|-----|----|-----|
|  2 |   b |  2 |   x |
|  3 |   c |  3 |   k |
|  3 |   d |  3 |   y |
```

**nb**: you could influence the final result by introducing `order by` in the subqueries that `group by id, val` where the sequence `RowInGroup` is calculated.

Comment: Don't you need to use two different variables for the two different row_nums?

Comment: no. the subqueries are self-contained due to the cross join where they get their initial values. you could of course use separate variables if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, that works! But that’s long, so I prefer my answer. Also, though performance is not a requirement in my case, your solution does not seem to be better complexity-wise.

Comment: I was not using your solution as a reference point. I was basing my solution on similar needs which are met by `ROW_NUMBER()` a function that is sadly missing from MySQL. This is a technique for producing the effect of row_number.  Its not that "long" really but I have spaced it out for legibility.

Comment: Reading & writing the same user variable in the same select statement is undefined behaviour--see the manual re variables & assignment.

Comment: And no longer required once everyone upgrades their MySQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it!

```
SELECT T.ID_A,
       T.VAL_A,
       T.XXXX,
       T.ID_B,
       T.VAL_B,
       T.YYYY
FROM (

SELECT A.id AS ID_A,
       A.VAL AS VAL_A,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID, A.VAL ORDER BY A.ID, A.VAL) AS XXXX,
       B.ID AS ID_B,
       B.VAL AS VAL_B,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.ID, B.VAL ORDER BY B.ID DESC, B.VAL) AS YYYY
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id) AS T
WHERE T.YYYY = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Copy-pasted as is, it gives me an SQL syntax error. I’ll investigate tomorrow.

Comment: Probably the OVER partition has a different Syntax in MySQL.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like ROW_NUMBER is not in MySQL. I tried to simulate it with a counting variable but could not make it.

Comment: It helped though, in that it made me search `ROW_NUMBER`, which lead me to the answer.

Comment: I dv'd, but only because this is clearly a solution for a different RDBMS